# Эмулятор 8-битного процессора

Tags: ассемблер, процессор, assembly, микроархитектура

Разбираюсь с [заданием с Yayza CTF](https://ctf.zeyu2001.com/2021/yauzactf-2021/risc-8bit-cpu): нужно по документации написать эмулятор 8-битного процессора. Во врайтапе есть код, в котором во время выполнения инструкций JNZ и JZ Program Counter перемещается по указанному адресу с прибавлением 4, а в JMP 4 не прибавляется.

**Почему нужно прибавлять и почему именно такое значение?**

[image: Фрагмент документации][image: Реализация на питоне]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Во врайтапе есть код, в котором во время выполнения инструкций JNZ и JZ Program Counter перемещается по указанному адресу с прибавлением 4, а в JMP 4 не прибавляется.

Вы что-то путаете - должно быть наоборот *(если речь идёт об CPU-x86)*.
В х86-32 архитектуре, переходы бывают **абсолютные**, и **относительные**.

1. При абсолютных, к указателю *(Programm Counter)* `EIP` прибавляется 32-битное смещение, в результате чего можно совершать прыжки вплоть до 4 ГБайт от текущего адреса. Безусловные переходы `JMP` и вызов функций `CALL` используют именно абсолютную адресацию, т.е. `EIP+4` байта.
2. Условные-же переходы `JZ/JNZ` всегда используют относительную адресацию, с прыжками только в диапазоне +/-128 байт от текущего значения `EIP`. Такие переходы кодируются всего 1 байтом со-знаком. Когда этот байт имеет положительное значение `00..7Fh`, значит переход осуществляется вперёд, если-же операнд отрицательный в диапазоне `80..FFh`, то соответственно `EIP` сместится назад.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Забыл уточнить, речь идет об архитектуре RISC, там может иначе как-то?

Comment: На счёт RISC точно не уверен, а в CISC именно так обстоят дела.

Comment: В x86-32 все переходы относительные, кроме косвенных (по адресу в регистре или в "ячейке" памяти). Просто смещение или 1-байтное, или 4-байтное, относительно начала следующей команды.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо! Теперь понял, в какую сторону копать